# How to count length of list with conditional exclusion of certain strings and numbers? Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, count

I have a list that I'd like to count, but first it needs to be cleaned up.

The list looks something like:

```
list= ['Skills & Endorsements', 'Problem Solving',  'See 9 endorsements for Problem Solving', '9']
```

I want to count the row, but exclude all numbers, and strings that have numbers in them. In this example, I would want to remove the number `9` and the item `See 9 endorsements for Problem Solving`.

I'm having trouble coming up with a conditional in Python, where 0 is if it violates the conditional, and 1 if it meets the conditions count if `!=` a number or a string that includes `See`.

Comment: Try use regular expression to check if it contains number or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to fo this is to use the `re` module to make a simple regex that matches numbers. Then you can put this in a list comprehension and ask for its length:

```
import re

l = ['Skills & Endorsements', 'Problem Solving',  'See 9 endorsements for Problem Solving', '9']  

# what the comprehension makes:
print([s for s in l if re.search(r'\d', s) is None])
# ['Skills & Endorsements', 'Problem Solving']

len([s for s in l if re.search(r'\d', s) is None])
# 2
```

Comment: You got downvoted because of me (i think). check my answer's comment

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese I actually downvoted your answer and was making a comment when you deleted it. It didn't work at all because of the spaces in the strings.

Comment: I suppose, if one of the list elements was *actually* a number (`9`), rather than a string representation (`'9'`), this would break. That might be why it got downvoted. using `re.search(r'\d', str(s))` would resolve that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[i for i in list1 if not any(j.isnumeric() for j in i)]
```

This filters out items without numbers in them.

```
['Skills & Endorsements', 'Problem Solving']
```

Comment: This works now. I don't think you really need the `split()` though.

Comment: @MarkMeyer then?

Comment: 'See 9 endorsements for Problem Solving' is not numeric

Comment: Right, but `any(j.isnumeric() for j in 'See 9 endorsements for Problem Solving')` is `True`. You don't need to split it. The iterator looks at every character.

Comment: @MarkMeyer now is it ok?

Comment: Yup that's a +1 for me.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use `re` to check if there is a number in string ot not

```
import re
list= ['Skills & Endorsements', 'Problem Solving',  'See 9 endorsements for Problem Solving', '9']
count = len([e for e in list if not re.findall('\d', e)])
```

The regex in this example trying to find all the numbers `\d` may appear in each element. If there is no number, it will "count" this element and add it to a temporary list. Finally, we just need to get the `len` of this temporary list to know how many elements in it

Comment: what is the difference between using ```re.findall``` and ```re.search``` as a solution?

Comment: Check it out here for more information: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-findall-methods-in-python-regular-expressions

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```py
mylist = ['Skills & Endorsements', 'Problem Solving',  'See 9 endorsements for Problem Solving', '9']

print([s for s in mylist if not any(c.isdigit() for c in s)])
```

Output:

```
['Skills & Endorsements', 'Problem Solving']
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a method with your condition and then iterate elements of list over the function

```
In [26]: def my_cond(x):
    ...:     return  any(map(str.isdigit, x))
    ...:
    ...:

In [27]: print(sum(1 for x in list2 if not my_cond(x)))
2
```

The function would check if any character in the string is digit or not based on that it would return true or false.